# Utilizar BETWEEN en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Necesito mostrar en la consulta la información que no sea mayor a 120 días al día de hoy por lo cual pienso que podría utilizar `BETWEEN` pero, no se como utilizarlo de la manera correcta para saber que día corresponde hace 120 días.

```
SELECT NOMBRE, PUESTO, FECHA
FROM EMPLEADOS
WHERE FECHA BETWEEN valor AND 2018-09-04
```

Comment: Solo te faltarían las comillas en la segunda fecha, intenta con: `WHERE FECHA BETWEEN valor AND '2018-09-04'`

Comment: Puedes escribir tu consulta de este modo: `SELECT NOMBRE, PUESTO, FECHA
FROM EMPLEADOS
WHERE FECHA BETWEEN DATEADD(DD,-120,GETDATE() ) AND GETDATE();`

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el _create_ de la tabla?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba esto

```
DATEADD(DAY, -120, GETDATE())
```

Mas info https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2):

Prueba usando esto, le aplico **CONVERT** para evitar que filtre la hora también:

```
SELECT NOMBRE, PUESTO, FECHA
FROM EMPLEADOS
WHERE FECHA 
BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -120, GETDATE())) 
AND     CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
```